# Can't login to my Stack Overflow account

Tags: support, openid, login

I used my homepage as my OpenID, delegated to `jigarashah.blogpost.com`. Now my homepage is down permanently, and when I try to login through blogger it tells me it's a new account. I am [user 129795](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129795/jigar-shah). What can I do now?

Even when I add my `subscriptions [aatt] jigarshah.net` email for notification, it says "email already registered", but when I use it to recover my account it says "not found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part makes sense. If you registered with your homepage URL, that's the only URL Stack Overflow knows -- it doesn't (and shouldn't, really) realize that the URL was delegating to `jigarashah.blogpost.com`, so that URL is unconnected to your account.

I'm not sure why account recovery isn't working though; if `subscriptions at jigarshah.net` (you realize you spelled it differently from the blogpost URL? is that the problem?) is the e-mail you used when you registered it should work. However, account recovery won't help -- all it does is tell you the OpenID(s) you have connected to your account in case you've forgotten them. Changing them is more complicated; you'll probably need to contact `team@stackoverflow.com` to have someone help you directly

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste/73801#73801) old answer for merging accounts might help, though I'm not certain it's directly applicable in your case since it looks like your old OpenID provider might have killed your OpenID. Go ahead and attempt the fixes it mentions and wait to see if they work. If not, you might need to email the Stack Overflow team.